# How to move latest date 500 files in linux

Tags: linux

in one directory i have 10000 files, so i need to move only 500 files with latest date via linux command line . Some one please help me on this , thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you need to combine this:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12976/how-to-move-100-files-from-a-folder-containing-thousands

with this:
https://www.tecmint.com/sort-ls-output-by-last-modified-date-and-time/